# unevenly spaced time series: moving sum in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation, moving-average

I am trying to figure out how to apply rolling function to unevenly spaced time series data.

The column that is defining space between the values to be sumed, called `id1`, is an integer, and could be representing arbitrary time units (nanoseconds, hours, years, etc.).

In below simplified example of my problem I am trying to apply `sum` on a window of length 3 of an index. `idf.rolling(3).sum()` seems to be ignoring index in this case. How can I make it respect integer index?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'id1': [0,1,2,5,6,8],
  'v1': [1,2,3,4,5,6]
})
idf = df.set_index('id1', drop=True)
idf.rolling(3).sum()
#       v1
#id1      
#0     NaN
#1     NaN
#2     6.0
#5     9.0
#6    12.0
#8    15.0
```

Expected results are:

```
#       v1
#id1      
#0     NaN
#1     NaN
#2     6.0
#5     4.0
#6     9.0
#8    11.0
```

I am looking for the most efficient solution in terms of time and memory. Therefore expanding original data by filling in missing index entries is not an option because index may be very sparse and materializing empty NaN entries will lead to an out of memory error.

Answer (score 2):

[`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) uses a number of rows as window… except if you use time-aware objects.

A workaround would be to define your index with a specific unit of time. For example seconds:

```
out = (df.set_axis(pd.to_timedelta(df['id1'], unit='s'))[['v1']]
         .rolling('3s').sum()
      )
out.index = out.index.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
       v1
id1      
0.0   1.0
1.0   3.0
2.0   6.0
5.0   4.0
6.0   9.0
8.0  11.0
```

Note that you lose the NaNs, if those are important, you could manually mask the N-1 top rows:

```
N = 3
out = (df.set_axis(pd.to_timedelta(df['id1'], unit='s'))[['v1']]
         .rolling(f'{N}s').sum()
      )
out.index = out.index.total_seconds()
out.iloc[:N-1] = np.nan
```

Or to mimic the behavior of `min_periods`:

```
N = 3
min_periods = 3
out = (df.set_axis(pd.to_timedelta(df['id1'], unit='s'))[['v1']]
         .rolling(f'{N}s').sum()
      )
out.index = out.index.total_seconds()
out.iloc[:min_periods-1] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
       v1
id1      
0.0   NaN
1.0   NaN
2.0   6.0
5.0   4.0
6.0   9.0
8.0  11.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I must not to lose those NaNs, and double rolling sounds very inefficient. Any solution for that?

Comment: Yes actually, the N-1 top rows should be NaN, you can you just overwrite those with NaNs, it's much more efficient. See update

Answer (score 1):

With a vectorized approach:

```
condition1 = df['id1'].diff(2).eq(2)
condition2 = df['id1'].diff(1).isin([1, 2])

a = np.column_stack([df['v1'].shift(i, fill_value=0) for i in range(3)])
b = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(df)), condition2, condition1])

df['v1'] = np.sum(a * b, axis=1)

df.loc[:1, 'v1'] = np.nan
```

Or faster:

```
condition1 = df['id1'].diff(2).eq(2)
condition2 = df['id1'].diff(1).isin([1, 2])

a = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
    np.pad(df['v1'], (2, 0), constant_values=0), 3)[:, ::-1]
b = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(df)), condition2, condition1])

df['v1'] = np.sum(a * b, axis=1)

df.loc[:1, 'v1'] = np.nan
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
from more_itertools import windowed

df = df.set_index('id1', drop=True)

df['v1'] = (([np.nan]*2) +
[np.dot(
    df.loc[x, :].values.reshape(-1), 
    np.array([(x[2]-x[0]) == 2, (x[2]-x[1]) in [1, 2], True]))
 for x in windowed(df.index, n=3)])
```

---

Yet another possible solution:

```
d = df.set_index('id1', drop=True)
d.reindex(range(df['id1'].max()+1)).fillna(0).rolling(3).sum().iloc[d.index]
```

---

Output:

```
       v1
id1      
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     6.0
5     4.0
6     9.0
8    11.0
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution materialize all NaNs? Imagine index having [0, 1, 2, 1000000000]. It will OOM, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But do you have indexes like `[0, 1, 2, 1000000000]`?

Comment: I have data up to 1e9 rows having indices up to 2e9. Not super sparse, yet I need to avoid materializing NaNs due to OOM.

Comment: @jangorecki: I have just vectorized my approach. Please, see it.